# sending emails form different forms in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I need some help pls.
I'm building this website using C.I 3 and it has like 3 different forms with 3 different pages (career, quote, contact) where users can fill them up and i will receive an email but only contact page is working and the remain two pages prompt and error (Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method) while they all fall under the same controller. can anyone help me solve this issue pls?
below is the link to my codes

http://pastebin.com/REFjPsUf

Thanks

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $this->home();
}
public function home(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("home_content");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}
public function aboutUs(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("content_about");
    $this->load->view("footer");
}
public function projects(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("content_project");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}
public function services(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("content_service");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}
public function careers(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("content_career");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}
public function gallery(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("content_gallery");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}
public function register(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("slider");
    $this->load->view("quote");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}


public function contact(){
    $this->load->view("home_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("contact_header");
    $this->load->view("content_contact");
    $this->load->view("footer");

}


public function sendmail(){




    $this->load->library('email');



    $this->email->from($this->input->post("email"), $this->input->post("name"));
    $this->email->to("me@example.com");


    $this->email->subject('from website contact form');

    $this->email->message($this->input->post("message"));


    if ( ! $this->email->send())
    {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger(); // Generate error
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view("home_header");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("contact_header");
        $this->load->view("contact_success");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }


}


public function quotation(){




    $this->load->library('email');



    $this->email->from($this->input->post("email"));
    $this->email->to("me@example.com");


    $this->email->subject($this->input->post("subject"));

    $this->email->message($this->input->post("message"));


    if ( ! $this->email->send())
    {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger(); // Generate error
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view("home_header");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("slider");
        $this->load->view("quote_success");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
} 


public function mycareer(){


    $this->load->library('email');



    $this->email->from($this->input->post("email"));
    $this->email->to("me@example.com");

    $this->email->subject($this->input->post("subject"));

    $this->email->message($this->input->post("message"));

    if (!$this->email->send()){
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
    else{
        echo "Email sent";
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please include the relevant code parts you have problems with to have [mcve], else likely noone will going to be able to help you.

Comment: I just inserted the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is an error in your code in last two functions "`quotation() and mycareer()`" missing of 2nd argument in `$this->email->from()`

[reference link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

```
$this->email->from($this->input->post("email") , 'Your Name');
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**try on smtp config in ci as

```
$this->email->initialize(array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'xxxx.ipage.com',//SMTP servern name
  'smtp_user' => 'user@xxxx.com',
  'smtp_pass' => 'SMTP user password',
  'smtp_port' => 587,//port
  'crlf' => "\r\n",
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'newline' => "\r\n",
'wordwrap' => TRUE
));

$this->email->from($email,$name);
$this->email->to('admin@xxxx.com'); 
$this->email->cc('user@xxxx.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('xxxxx@gmail.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message($message1);   

if($this->email->send())
echo "<script>alert('Thank you... mail Sent');</script>";
else
echo "<script>alert('Not Sent Please Try again');</script>";
redirect('xxxx/abc');
```

OR you can use PHP-mail class also.. just download from GitHub or in php official site. then paste it in view folder then include it.. that's it.

```
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
//date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require __DIR__.'/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
//$mail->DKIM_domain = '160.153.33.231';
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host        = "mail.xxxx.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port        = 465;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username    = "info@xxxxx.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password    = "xxxxx";
$mail->SMTPSecure  = 'ssl';

if(isset($from,$sender)){
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom($from, $sender);
}
else $mail->setFrom("info_@xxxxx.com", 'from Website');



//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('info_@xxxx.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('care@xxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxx.com');

//$mail->AddBCC('xxxx@gmail.com','');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML($body_tmp);
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
//echo $body_tmp;
?>**
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have a very common error a lot of people have with "Contact Us" forms.

```
$this->email->from($this->input->post("email"));
```

This will break SPF and also cause DMARC to fail and you will never get the message from some people, if your mail server you use has DMARC enabled on it.

Since DMARC is a more recent protocol, a lot of the old cookie cutter code for contact us forms - doesn't take this into account.

You can read more about that here: ["DMARC - Contact Form Nightmare"](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

The suggested workaround will be to do:

```
$this->email->from("me@example.com");
$this->email->subject($this->input->post("subject") . $this->input->post("email") );
```

This way - you avoid the issue outline in the article. You won't quickly be able to hit the "Reply" button, but at least you'll get the emails from those customers who have DMARC enabled.